# Very high CPU usage with GPU mining

Tags: mining, gpu

I've now started mining with ethminer, however, even though it is correctly using my GPU (its usage is constantly at 100%), the program is also maxing out two of my four cores, to the point where their temperature is higher than the GPU's, I thought it was supposed not to use it, expecially because considering that using the CPU for mining is basically a waste of energy.

By the way, my graphics card is an NVIDIA gtx970 and my processor is an i7-4790k.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? same problem with ethminer here. (same processor as yours) and 4 gtx1070, win10

Comment: @Doug yes I did, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually found a solution the problem was not ethminer, but rather geth that for some reason was mining using the CPU. To solve it's enough to run geth with the command

```
geth --minerthreads 0
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't download and am not running geth? I just ran the ethminer itself, connected to a pool. Do I need to run geth on the background or something?

Answer (score 1):

Ive noted this before when using Nvidia and the stock Ubuntu ppa ethminer. I switched to genoils and the problem was solved .. my CPU's mow run around 3 - 4 % while mining

Answer (score 0):

change -G to -U solved this for me.

-G,--opencl  When mining use the GPU via OpenCL.
-U,--cuda  When mining use the GPU via CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (unfortunately many), the processors in Windows 10 show 100% usage.
From what I understand the problem grows according to the number of GPUs.
Windows 10 overloads processors that have few flames when GPUs are more than the threads.

I found some tweaks for windows 10 and achieve more than 50% less CPU usage.

New CPU Usage: 45%

[Windows10MiningTweaksDmW](https://github.com/DeadManWalkingTO/Windows10MiningTweaksDmW)

Just let me know about your results.

Have a nice mining!